# Arbitrarily run method during ngFor loop (Angular 5)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an angular page, where, during an *ngFor loop, I want to update a variable, then write it to the HTML during each iteration of the loop.

Like so:

HTML:

```
<table *ngFor="let data of Dataset">
somehowRunThis(data)
<div>{{methodResult}}</div>
</table>
```

TS:

```
...
methodResult: any;
...
somehowRunThis(data): {
let a;
...
this.methodResult = a;
}
```

etc etc.

Is there any way this can work? Attempting to add a method that returns within the curly brackets seems to not work, and there appears to be no effective way to run arbitrary methods from the HTML in Angular.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you want to trigger this update in HTML?

Depending on your needs you can use pipe (https://angular.io/guide/pipes) or transform the data to desired format in your component.
I would say it's not a good idea to have a method with side-call effects invoked in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. A general advice: sometimes we are looking for an answer in the wrong places, be open :)

Instead of forcing ngFor, just run a simple array.map on your data before sending it to the template.

```
displayData = this.data.map(el => this.somehowRunThis(el))
```

this way you'll avoid having terrible performance.

If you don't care and still want to do this thing for some reason you can make your function return it and actually call in template:

```
{{ myFunctionReturnsText() }}
```

**This is a bad idea because the function calls will run on each change detection so something like Pipes/Directives will be better.**